# aws lambda public url showing blank page?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When I try to invoke the `lambda` function using a public url I don't see any output.

```
# Lambda function
import json
import hmac, base64, struct, hashlib, time

sec = 'my_secret'

def get_hotp_token(secret, intervals_no):
    key = base64.b32decode(secret, True)
    msg = struct.pack(">Q", intervals_no)
    h = hmac.new(key, msg, hashlib.sha1).digest()
    o = h[19] & 15
    h = (struct.unpack(">I", h[o:o+4])[0] & 0x7fffffff) % 1000000
    return h

def get_totp_token(secret):
    return get_hotp_token(secret, intervals_no=int(time.time())//30)


def lambda_handler(event, totp):
    # totp = get_totp_token(sec)
    # print(totp)
    return {
        'statusCode' : 200,
        'totp' : get_totp_token(sec)
    }
```

When I test the function using `aws-console` I get the desired output.

I went to `Configuration---->Function URL---->Create Function Url---->Auth type---->None----> Cors---->Yes`. Saved with default settings of `CORS`.

Now when I use the URL I get a blank page.

Comment: Lamba returned body should be a string.  Are you returning a string? Or object/dict? Please confirm

Comment: @Mercury thanks for pointing it out. I just double checked and if I return the `totp` rather than `dict`/`json` it gives me the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lamba body response should be a **string**, Not an object/ dict.
If you want to return a dict you'l need to stringify it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html